# What happened if two DDR 3 RAM with different max bandwidths

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have laptop 8440p and it has two DDR3 Ram one ram max bandwidth is **PC3-8500F 533 Mhz** but the  other has PC3 10700 (667 Mhz) what is the effect on the laptop performance and the parts of the laptops like HDD, Processor etc

Answer (score 1):

The 667 MHz one will most likely be underclocked to 533 MHz by the motherboard.
So you can improve performance slighty by changing the 533 MHz chip to a 667 MHz one.

You will notice no improvement for CPU, HDD that I know of.

**You are better of replacing the HDD with a SSD if you want speed increase.**